# rails '.variable' notation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking over the [source code](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/blob/master/app/views/home/index.html.erb) for rubygems.org to further understand Rails and how to use it with a functional site.

One question I have is what exactly do these do?:

```
<%= t 'download_count', :count => number_with_delimiter(@downloads_count) %>
<%= t '.welcome_blurb' %>
```

Are `download_count` and `.welcome_blurb` variables that store the text somewhere? If so, where do I find that and how does it know where to look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`download_count` and `.welcome_blurb` are translated strings, you can find them in the `config/locales/` directory in a file with a filename corresponding to the language, in this case `en.yml` for English:

`download_count`: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml#L11
`.welcome_blurb`: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml#L31

The dot before `welcome_blurb` signifies a lazy lookup, which means that the namespace for the translation defaults to the view you are calling it from, as you'll see in the `en.yml` file:

```
home:
  index:
...
    welcome_blurb: "Welcome to your community RubyGem host."
```

So `.welcome_blurb` actually means `home.index.welcome_blurb`.

See the [rails i18n documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for more details.

Comment: also - if you only have the en.yml file it will not translate to, say, spanish right?

Comment: You're very welcome! And yes, if you don't have the es.yml file it will not translate to spanish. If you want translations to default to english or any other language, you can specify this in `application.rb` with `config.i18n.fallbacks = true`.

Answer (score 1):

`t` is a shorthand way of writing `I18n.translate`, which will use the locale files (likely in config/locales) to render text appropriate to the current language setting.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html for more details.